# SSIS can't run create excel file or save as copy excel file as a VBScript fine, (no error but nothing changed after execution)

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, vbscript, wsh

I have SSIS package that run the VBS file and this file includes:

CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlWorkbook.SaveCopyAs

commands.

Under my security privilege everything goes fine (I am Admin) but when I use SSIS service account (this account set as SQL server agent account that it should run the SSIS package) package run successfully but excel files doesn't update (obviously nothing changed). I modify the configuration of SSIS account for DCOM Config/Microsoft Excel Application (Authentication level: none, add SSIS to security tab and set identity to launching user) also I add SSIS service account to the security of all folders in this server).
Please help me on this issue??????? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the `Log on as a batch job permission`. Run secpol.msc from an admin account and add this user to this permission. See this question for more info

[SSIS runs package that runs powershell script but SSMS don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63308337/ssis-runs-package-that-runs-powershell-script-but-ssms-dont)

Comment: I did this stuff and the SSIS account has batch job permission and also it has proxy account with permission to execute all sub systems operations. But still my account (as DBA) can execute the job successfully (Excel Files Modified) but the SSIS account couldn't.

Comment: @PouyanNikzad  try "runas /user:...    cmd" . This will open a new CMD window running under the given user. If you do this for your SSIS account, then execute the VBS from command line, you may able to find the problem.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11)

Comment: @PouyanNikzad  make sure your VBS script does not have GUI prompts for user to answer. And use "cscript" instead of "wscript". That will suppress GUIs, including error GUI prompt that may cause your script to hang in wait