# SSIS runs package that runs powershell script but SSMS don't

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have a package on SSIS that executes a .BAT file that consequently executes a PowerShell file, which brings the file metadata from a folder, generating a CSV file.

I already granted access to the folder for the SQL Server Agent user, but it didn't work.

When I run the package on SSIS, it works correctly! However, if I execute the same package through a JOB in SSMS, it ends the step, but the .BAT file was not executed, or if it was, the Powershell file did not, because after the execution the CSV file is "1kb", no data.

Am I forgetting something?

SSIS package (portuguese language):

[image]

[EDIT 1]

A strange thing that I noticed, was that we have 3 packages scheduled by SSMS, but only one of them that doesn't work, which is the one mentioned in the question. But I can't find out why or what the difference is to others.

2 packages extract information from Sharepoint and work on SSMS, but this other package that extracts metadata from files does not.

Comment: Why use a bat file to the run a powershell file? Why not straight run the powershell file?

Comment: @Larnu Good question, I never tried to run the powershell straight from SSIS instead of running a BAT file before. Actually, I don't even know how to do it. But anyway, the package is working on SSIS, why doens't work as weel on SSMS?

Comment: Check the logs in SSISDB, they will expose more, provided you've added logging to your batch file.

Comment: Does the account that will be running PowerShell have the appropriate ExecutionPolicy set? Before PS6, the default will Restricted  `Get-ExecutionPolicy`  and you'll want to bump that to something, like Remote-Signed  `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Comment: @billinkc I added your line above my PS script, what I had before is `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process`

Comment: @billinkc I've added an update to my question, do you guys think of something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the job step's "Run As" value, which is a "Proxy" (visible in the Object Explorer in SSMS.
[image]

Open the Proxy (SQL Server Agent >> Proxies >> SSIS Package Execution).  It will list a Credential Name.

Open the Credential (Security >> Credentials).  It will list an Identity.  *That's* the user whose security needs to be configured.

Comment: I don't if did it right, but in my SQL Server Management Studio 18.5 (2019) there is no `run as` under advanced in the job steps. Also in the `Proxy` folder, it's empty. Should I do something?

Comment: It's under "General", not "Advanced".  See newly-added screenshot

Comment: I'm sorry, I was in the wrong tab for sure. The use in `Run As` is SQL Server Agent. But my `Proxy` folder is empty, also the `Credential` is the admin acount.

Comment: I've added a `Proxy` and changed the step to run as that user but it didn't work as well. Also, I updated the question with more information.

Comment: What does the job history show? Success or failure? Any detailed messages?

Comment: it shows success. But it seems that the Powershell script didn't succeed, because the CSV file was empty. But if I run through SSIS or the PS file itself, it works normally.

Comment: How is the script referencing the file? Named drive letters are user specific. Could that be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Open a `cmd` window and run `runas /user:<userGoesHere> cmd` and enter the password when prompted. See the [documentation of `runas` here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11))

Now, it opens a second `cmd` window which runs under this user used in the SQL Server Agent. Execute your batch file and see if you'll catch any error.

Also, the process you're running may require the user to have `Log on as a batch job` permission. Run `secpol.msc` from an admin  account and add this user to this permission.

[image: Log on as a batch job permission]